# Column filter using checkbox in angular

Tags: angular, primeng

Here what I am trying to achieve is: on clicking on the related checkbox only the table should display the columns.

[image]

```
<div class="column-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let columnName of columnData">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
      <p>{{columnName}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p-table [value]="sampleData" styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines p-datatable-sm" [tableStyle]="{'min-width': '50rem'}">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>passengerId</th>
          <th>survived</th>
          <th>Pclass</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
          <th>Ticket</th>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
      <tr>
          <td>{{data.passengerId}}</td>
          <td>{{data.survived}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Pclass}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Sex}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Ticket}}</td>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a boolean to each of the columns

```
export class YourComponent {
  columnVisibility = {
    passengerId: true,
    survived: true,
    Pclass: true,
    Name: true,
    Sex: true,
    Ticket: true
  };

  columnData = Object.keys(this.columnVisibility);
}
```

your html should look like this:

```
<div class="column-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let columnName of columnData">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="columnVisibility[columnName]">
      <p>{{columnName}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

table

```
<p-table [value]="sampleData" styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines p-datatable-sm" [tableStyle]="{'min-width': '50rem'}">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th *ngIf="columnVisibility.passengerId">passengerId</th>
      <th *ngIf="columnVisibility.survived">survived</th>
      <th *ngIf="columnVisibility.Pclass">Pclass</th>
      <th *ngIf="columnVisibility.Name">Name</th>
      <th *ngIf="columnVisibility.Sex">Sex</th>
      <th *ngIf="columnVisibility.Ticket">Ticket</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
    <tr>
      <td *ngIf="columnVisibility.passengerId">{{data.passengerId}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="columnVisibility.survived">{{data.survived}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="columnVisibility.Pclass">{{data.Pclass}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="columnVisibility.Name">{{data.Name}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="columnVisibility.Sex">{{data.Sex}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="columnVisibility.Ticket">{{data.Ticket}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some kind of boolean field to the columnData say `visible`.

```
<div class="column-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let columnName of columnData">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" [(ngModel)]="columnName.visible">
      <p>{{columnName.name}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can use it in your headers and rows to hide fields.

```
<tr *ngFor="let col of columnData">
   <th *ngIf="col.visible">{{col.name}}</th>
</tr>
```

This part doesn't need to be a loop if you wanted to define each individually. But it is cleaner imo to put them inside of one.